# Why is my B1S (Ubuntu) Azure VM maxing at 10% CPU when running a processor-intensive task?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to Azure, only exploring it right now (together with AWS & GCP at the same time) to identify what I can use it for in my professional life.

So now I'm running a B1S (1 vCPU, 1GB RAM) as part of the Free Trial. When I run a single long-running processor-intensive task (e.g. PDFCRACK), this is what I noticed:

1. "top" will say that this task is using around 100% CPU.
2. Azure Portal dashboard indicates the same thing (100% CPU), but only for a while (2-3 minutes), after that it goes down and stays at 10% CPU. At the same time, "top" still says that the task is using 100% CPU.

And the performance is really roughly 10% compared to an equivalent GCP setup (PDFCRACK reports the number of tries it made per second).

Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any explanation for this?

It is a by design behavior.

> The B-Series VMs work much differently than the other VM Series. You
>   pay for a baseline of vCPU performance utilization with the number of
>   vCPU cores allocated. Then you will accumulate and bank a number of
>   credits during the time when you only need that baseline vCPU
>   utilization percentage. Then when the VM needs to burst to 100% it can
>   do so when necessary and spend the banked credits to do so.

The B1S VM size has 1 vCPU allocated with a baseline CPU performance of 10%. This means that generally the VM can use up to 10% CPU utilization of that single vCPU. Then, the B1S VM will bank 6 credits per hour up to a maximum of 144 credits that can be banked when utilizing less than the base performance. Then when the VM needs more than 10% CPU it can burst up to use more CPU performance and spend the banked credits to do so.

More information about burstable vms, please refer to this [link](https://buildazure.com/2017/09/11/more-affordable-azure-vms-with-burstable-b-series/).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. I suppose I should have researched a bit more on the term "burstable" when I encountered it. (I thought it was about the capability to "burst" over 100% CPU for a limited time + some extra fees when necessary.) Well, at least this will serve as reference to other Azure newbies in the future.